# Do you really need a server for AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services

I want to deploy my AngularJS app which access RESTful web-services onto an aws and I am wondering if I really need a server to serve my AngularJS files.

I can server them as static files or use something like NodeJS but do I really need one?

What are the advantages/dis-advantages of using a server in this scenario?

Comment: once you deployed your code in aws your application will work fine. Because aws itself a server right. To run it locally u need a local server like tomcat.

Comment: How should the client access your angular app without a server serving the app?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is small, it's really not a problem if you only access to an API.

But if you want to login via other services where you have for example a public and secret token it's better to work with a server who use cache this datas from your users (maybe it's what your aws is doing).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access RESTFull Web Services from AWS, you need to put your angularjs files in a server.

The server will give access to resources, if the request is from **http** protocol. It will deny the request to serve if the protocol is **file**.